# How to create a wxPython button with a SVG icon?

Tags: button, svg, wxpython

I'm facing the deprecation warnings

```
wxPyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated item ImageFromStream. Use :class:`Image` instead.
  svgimg = wx.ImageFromStream(StringIO.StringIO(svgpng),wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
wxPyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated item BitmapFromImage. Use :class:`wx.Bitmap` instead
 svgbmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(svgimg)
```

for

```
def getBmpFromSvg(self,svgxml, width, height):
    """
    Credit goes to https://cyberxml.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/wxpython-wx-bitmap-icons-from-svg-xml/. Asked https://cyberxml.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/wxpython-wx-bitmap-icons-from-svg-xml/comment-page-1/#comment-11 to a version avoiding deprecated wx.BitmapFromImage.
    """
    svgpng = cairosvg.svg2png(svgxml)
    svgimg = wx.ImageFromStream(StringIO.StringIO(svgpng),wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
    svgimg = svgimg.Scale(width, height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
    svgbmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(svgimg)
    return svgbmp

playButtonImg = self.getBmpFromSvg(resource_string("[name]", os.path.join("resources", "icons", 'play-button.svg')), icon_size_default, icon_size_default)
self.playButton = buttons.GenBitmapButton(self.videoPanel, bitmap=playButtonImg, name="play")
```

and I don't seem to find information on how to create an SVG icon for a button from [Icon's documentation](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Icon.html) (stating that icons are supposed to be bitmaps which seems a bit outdated given the time SVG is around) and [the icons overview](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/bitmap_overview.html#bitmaps-and-icons). [Button's documentation](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Button.html) mentions bitmaps only as well.

Even if I have to work with bitmaps, I'd like to eliminate the deprecation warnings.

I'm using Phoenix 9b743cf3 (they fail to use `git` tags) built from source on Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 1):

The warning tells you how to correct it. `wx.Image` can accept a stream the first argument (instead of `wx.ImageFromStream`) and `wx.Bitmap` can accept a `wx.Image` as the first argument (instead of `wx.BitmapFromImage`)

See also [wx.Image.ConvertToBitmap](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Image.html#wx.Image.ConvertToBitmap)